# How to make my web page look the same on IE8, IE9, Chrome and FF

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a table that the styling is off on ie8 and does not appear at all in ie9 - but looks good in Chrome and FF.  I adjusted the pixels and margins, but nothing changes in ie8 and ie9 doesn't even load the page properly.

I am using moveable type and new to css and html lingo.  Here is a link: http://www.longworth.com/portfolio.html.  Note sure how to send a pic to compare the table that is off the margins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I don't want to throw in the towel just yet.  Many thanks!

Comment: I'm sort of wondering why the source of that page has like 3000+ blank lines...

Answer (score 0):

You can add special instructions for IE only. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for more details.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Inside of `ie8.css` you can have styles that fix the weirdness you are seeing, but that won't effect the layout for Chrome or Firefox. Rinse and repeat for IE9.